# Is there a possible way to use char in strcmp?

Tags: c, scanf, strcmp

I have this program that's supposed to be a 'chat simulator', the only thing it's supposed to do now is replying 'Hello!' when the user types 'Hello'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Chat simulator!\n");
   do {
      char x;
      printf("[User1] ");
      scanf("%s",&x);
      if (strcmp (x,"Hello") == 0)
      {
         Sleep(1500);
         printf("[User2] Hello!\n");
      }
      else {}
   } while(1);
}
```

I know that `strcmp` is only for `const char *`, not a single `char`, and that's the problem here, but I couldn't find any other solution for this, since I need to use `char x` in `scanf`, so it can't be a `const char *`.
 Also it may be possible that I'm using `strcmp` wrong.
Code:Blocks warning:

```
passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without a cast*
expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'*
```

**Edit:**

So I changed the `char` to `char[16]` as @robin.koch told me, and it's all working as it should. Thanks!

Comment: why do you try to store the user's message (the whole message) inside a `char`?

Comment: The problem is not where you think it is. `x` is a single `char`, while you are trying to stuff a string (array of characters) into it.

Comment: x is only ONE character. You are trying to store a string (multiple characters). Use a char array instead. char x[16]; for example.

Comment: @robin.koch Thanks, now it's working as it should, but Code:Block is still giving me a warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[16]' [-Wformat=]

Comment: `char x;` & then `scanf("%s",&x);` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `char x[16]; .... scanf("%s",&x);` --> `scanf("%15s",/* no & */ x);`

Comment: @chux Thanks, no warnings now.

Comment: @mnpj22 Tip: do not use `scanf()` to read a _line_ of user input.  Recommend `fgets()`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare a string with a `char` with `strcmp`, but it is easy to do by hand:

```
int samechar(const char *str, char c) {
    return *str == c && (c == '\0' || str[1] == '\0');
}
```

The above function however is not what you need for you problem:

- You should read a string from the user, not a single char.
- `scanf()` needs a pointer to a `char` array for the conversion specifier `%s`.
- Furthermore you should specify the maximum number of characters to store into the this array to avoid potential a buffer overflow.
- Finally, `scanf()` will only read a single word.  You probably want to read a full line from the user.  Use `fgets()` for this.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Chat simulator!\n");
    for (;;) {
        char buf[100];
        printf("[User1] ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';  /* strip the newline if present */
        if (strcmp(buf, "Hello") == 0) {
            printf("[User2] Hello!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Covering the trivial case of `c == '\0'`: `return *str == c && (c == '\0' || str[1] == '\0');`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're trying to store a string into a `char` variable using `scanf` when chars are only meant to store one character. You should you use a `char *` or `char[]` variable to hold your string instead. So change

```
char x;
printf("[User1] ");
scanf("%s",&x);
//...rest of your code...
```

to

```
char * x = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); //can hold up to ten characters
printf("[User1] ");
scanf("%s",x);
//...rest of your code...
free(x);
```

Note that if you just want to use a char array instead of a pointer you can replace the first line above with something like `char x[10];` and get rid of `free(x);`